# collect vs collectFirst - why the return values are of different type - Scala

Tags: scala

The question is to confirm if I have correctly understood the use of Option.

I notice that method collect returns a List while collectFirst returns an Option. Is it because collect can return multiple values or none (none being represented by an empty list). collectFirst on other hand returns a single value (or nothing) and thus it makes more to use an Option as we will never return a 'list'

Comment: Strictly speaking, collect does not return multiple values or none, but a single value, which happen to be either a collection containing multiple values, or an empty collection. But you still have something in both cases.

Comment: I think you got the idea. It also makes sense to think of an Option as a collection with a maximum size of 1 at times. Option supports many operations you would find on a that as well (e.g.  `map()`, `foreach()`, ..). With this line of thinking the two return types are not that different - both are collections, one is just limited in size, the other is not.

Comment: kinda ... sorta ... yes! Duh!

Comment: Yup... you are right. For exactly those reasons, `List` is a suitable choice for the `collect` and `Option` is for `collectFirst`

Comment: @PavelOliynyk What is the relevance of that link in this discussion ?

Answer (score 12):

You are right:

```
scala> (1 to 5).collect { case i if i % 2 == 0 => "*" * i }
res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(**, ****)

scala> (1 to 5).collectFirst { case i if i % 2 == 0 => "*" * i }
res: Option[String] = Some(**)

scala> (1 to 5).collect { case i if i > 10 == 0 => "*" * i }
res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector()

scala> (1 to 5).collectFirst { case i if i > 10 == 0 => "*" * i }
res: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Thus `collectFirst` is equivalent to `collect { } .headOption`. and because `collectFirst` is doing two things collecting and taking first it needs to resort to `Option` in case the collection is empty.